# cache in .dll with asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, linq, dll, ado.net, webforms

I have a site that uses a dll developed with vs2010.

In dll i have a method `C.GetData(int id)` that return a `IEnumerable` collection of my object. When i use a repeater to display data, i see the "old" data.  For example, in the database I have `name=Maurox`, but in .aspx page I see `name=Pippo` that is the old value of field before update.

If i use the same query (copy/paste from method `C.GetDate`) the data is ok, i see name=Maurox on may page.

Here is an example:

> with C.GetData() i have this row (wrong) 51           Via Roma    Firenze 00100
>
> with "inline" linq (copy/paste linq query in code behind) i have: 51
>         Via Roma    Firenze **00101**

the query is simple:

```
from c in db.ContattiRecapiti
join cc in db.Contatti on c.idcontatto equals cc.IDContatto
join aa in db.aspnet_Membership on cc.aspnet_UserId equals aa.UserId
where cc.aspnet_UserId == UserId && cc.Attivo == 1 && aa.IsApproved == true && c.attivo == 1
select c
```

How i can fix this?  Is there some cache??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework, there is an internal object cache, which is the implementation of the Unit of Work pattern that the Data/Object Context employs.  What you could try to do is call the [Refresh()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503718.aspx) method to see if it refreshes the data for you...

Also, how do you store your data/object context?  Do you store it globally, or for each LINQ query?

Comment: Ok, this seems to solve my problem. I have inserted `db.Refresh(System.Data.Objects.RefreshMode.StoreWins, C);` before return C. I store it for each linq query

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are calling the function properly???
Please make sure that you calling the function to display.. you may be used it within ispostback function or something else. I dont think there is a separate cache within dll. the browsers cache may not be cleared. Also, please check the data after refreshing(ctrl+F5) the page